# Bigquery Javascript UDF using storage and kms libraries

Tags: node.js, encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to develop a Bigquery Javascript UDF for AES decryption.
The key used for AES encryption is encrypted and stored in GCS.
I have developed a Javascript code , which will do the following steps:

1. Read the file having encrypted  value of AES key from GCS
2. Decrypt the AES key value using kms keyring and kms key
3. Use this key for AES decryption.

I am getting storage and kms libraries using below statements:

const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const kms = require('@google-cloud/kms');

When I have to call the same functionality from Bigquery UDF, how will I make
sure these libraries are available? (I don't want to hard code the AES key in the Bigquery UDF)

I have seen an option for   [OPTIONS (library = library_array)] in Bigquery UDF definition, but I
am not sure which specific .js files are required for storage and kms integration?

## Code snippet

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage.Storage();
const kms = require('@google-cloud/kms');
const client = new kms.KeyManagementServiceClient();
bucketName ="gs://testbucket"
const keyFile = storage.bucket(bucketName).file("key.enc");
'use strict';

  async function decrypt(ciphertext){
   const name=<replace with crypto-key-path>;
   const [result] = await client.decrypt({name, ciphertext});
   return Buffer.from(result.plaintext, 'base64').toString();
  }
   var key=saltFile.download(function(err, contents) { 
     key=decrypt(contents);
     key.then(function (value) {
            key = value.trim();
            console.log(value);     
        });
     return key;
   })
```

Thank you,
Anu

Answer (score 1):

- To answer the question: You can store the key in a GCS file, and read it by importing the file as an additional .js.

But:

- BigQuery UDFs can't call external APIs, so even if '@google-cloud/storage' imports successfully, it won't be able to run and perform additional API calls.

Comment: Hi Felipe,Thanks for your reply. I am wondering whether there is a way to upload js files to storage bucket and point to them using OPTIONS (library = library_array). I tried the same for AES.js and its working.But for storage and kms there are many other dependencies listed in the js file,so makes it hard to upload one by one to google cloud bucket

Comment: just in case, are you aware of native BigQuery encryption functions? they do support several AES modes:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead-encryption-concepts